# Parallax scrolling on mobile devices jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile

How can I make this parallax scroll work on mobile devices ? It works fine on all browsers but not on mobile devices with touch screens.

```
// scoll images    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        }); 
    });    
});
```

Comment: You might want to consider rewriting your script using Skrollr / Skrollorama - both of which have mobile parallax support.

Comment: Thanks @leaksterrr I will give one of them ago.